# html table text to json data with pure js (selenium)

Tags: javascript, html, json, selenium

I am pretty new in programming and in JS, so what am I trying to do is (using Selenium Webdriver on Visual Code) to go and grab html table content from a page and convert it into JSON Data. I succeed with grabbing table data, but the conversion seems really tough.

So please help me with the struggle I am having, if anybody did it before...
Thanks

Sorry guys for being abstract a bit, so here is my code .....

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
        until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

    driver.get('https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp');

driver.sleep(15000).then(function () {

    var table = [];

for (var i = 2; i < 8; i++) {

    for (var k = 1; k < 4; k++) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="customers"]/tbody/tr[' + 
        i + ']/td[' + k + ']')).getText().then(function(name){
            table.push(name);
        });
    }
}
driver.sleep(10000).then(function () {

    console.log(table);

    });
});
```

And here is output...

```
[ 'Alfreds Futterkiste',
  'Maria Anders',
  'Germany',
  'Centro comercial Moctezuma',
  'Francisco Chang',
  'Mexico',
  'Ernst Handel',
  'Roland Mendel',
  'Austria',
  'Island Trading',
  'Helen Bennett',
  'UK',
  'Laughing Bacchus Winecellars',
  'Canada',
  'Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti',
  'Giovanni Rovelli',
  'Italy',
  'Yoshi Tannamuri' ]
```

And I want the data in JSON format , something like this ....

```
[
{ 'Company': 'Alfreds Futterkiste', 'Contact': 'Maria Anders', 
'Country': 'Germany'} ,
{ 'Company': 'Centro comercial Moctezuma', 
'Contact': 'Francisco Chang', 'Country': 'Mexico'} ,
```

....... and so on....

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Some code would be useful.

Comment: Pleaase review [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple ways you could solve this, simplest and maybe most lazy way of doing it is having a temporary array to store each column.

```
    var table = [];

for (var i = 2; i < 8; i++) {
    var tempArray = [];
    for (var k = 1; k < 4; k++) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="customers"]/tbody/tr[' + 
        i + ']/td[' + k + ']')).getText().then(function(name){
                 tempArray.push(name);
                        });
        table.push({"Company":tempArray[0], "Contact":tempArray[1], "Country":tempArray[2]});
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful.